# How to use formula for Bolds and then do something?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose this is my Excel Online:

```
Name    Price    Date             Debt   Pay
A        $        2022/0/12/25     5
A        $        2022/0/12/27     6
```

I want to use this in another cell to check this:

> if d:d is bold and name=A and Price=$ or "Dollar", then sum(d:d) - minus(e:e)

I want to create an Excel to write how much I should pay to others and how much they should pay me (for myself use only).

I searched some sites but none of them worked and I got formula error.

I mention that I use Excel Online (I think some formulas are different between Online and Installed version).

Comment: Formulas cannot detect format of cells.

Comment: @ScottCraner I see some websites write a function. Can they detect it? Or I should do a workaround like adding another column like `current` to calculate in formula?

Comment: if you want to use formula then you will need something beside the format to trigger, so having a column to indicate would be a good way of doing it.  If you want to use office scripts to script something that will also work.

Comment: What is the reason cells in column D are bold? Is that a conditional formatting rule, or manually done? If it's a rule we can use that.

Comment: @P.b no I use it manually. For example I should pay you 5$ and I haven't paid yet, then I make it bold manually. When I did my payment to you, I do it unbold.

Comment: You would need VBA or instead not make it bold, but use a helper cell.

Comment: Do yourself a favor: use a real value in a cell, not formatting, to maintain information/data in your spreadsheets. An extra column for "Paid", for instance. This is no doubt what P.b. means here by a helper cell. Relying on formatting can paint you into corners you don't want to be in in the long run.

Comment: I did a workaround by adding a `Is Paid` column and added an if to sum all `No` in `Is Paid` columns.